# Tunning Oracle Apex page

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, oracle-apex

[image: Page Debugging]

I've utilized debugging on the page, and I'm currently working on optimizing the page loading performance in Apex.

What would these items be? Is there any way to improve this time?

I've attempted to research this issue, but unfortunately, I haven't found any conclusive results. I'm genuinely keen on enhancing the performance, and any assistance would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/about-best-practices-to-improve-performance.htm#HTMDB29381) for improving performance. As noone but you know about your application, priorities of the components/processes etc., you should decide on the unnecessary events.

However, my suggestion is you also check one of the best built-in functionality of Apex, called Advisor:[image: Apex advisor2]

You can reach to advisor in the App Builder by your application -> Utilities -> Advisor. There are some options to include/exclude and I suggest you focus on the performance section.

Hope it helps.